# Weird issue with storing and unsetting session from redirect in Google Chrome with PHP

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, redirect, session-variables

I'm getting a weird issue only in **Google Chrome**. (It's fine in Firefox, IE) The code is below to recreate this. The steps are:

1. Navigate to a page that sets a session variable and redirects
2. The new destination page calls a function that:

   1. Reads the session variable and stores it in a local variable
   2. unsets the session variable
   3. returns the local variable
3. Then the page reads the return value and echos it into the HTML (or tries to)

I see two things:

1. If I call echo before the first output of the page, it echos it into the browser **but not** into the actual source (i.e. "view source" will not show the text I "echo"-ed)
2. If I call echo within the HTML, it doesn't echo it and doesn't print it into the source at all

The page that redirects (you can go directly to this page)

```
<?php
class LandingRedirector
{
    private static $SESSION_VARIABLE = "redirectedFrom";

    function __construct() {}

    public function redirect()
    {
        //Make sure we have a session
        session_start();

        //Set the redirect variable
        $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ] = "red.php";

        session_write_close();

        //Redirect to correct page
        header( "Location: /end.php" );
        exit();
    }

    //Call this and this correctly prints the value
    public function setonly()
    {
        //Make sure we have a session
        session_start();

        //Set the redirect variable
        $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ] = "red.php";

        session_write_close();
    }

    public function getRedirect()
    {
        try
        {
            //Make sure we have a session
            session_start();

            //It's set
            if ( isset( $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ] ) )
            {
                $redFrom = $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ];

                //Unset it
                unset( $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ] );

                return $redFrom;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {}

        return null;
    }
}

//Create
$redirector = new LandingRedirector();

//Redirect
if ( !isset( $stopHere ) || $stopHere != true ) $redirector->redirect();
?>
```

The destination page

```
<?php
    $stopHere = true;

    //Handles any redirect code
    require_once $_SERVER[ "DOCUMENT_ROOT" ] . "/red.php";

    //Were we redirected?
    $redirectOrigin = $redirector->getRedirect();

    //This echos into the browser but is NOT in the page when you "view source"
    if ( $redirectOrigin ) echo $redirectOrigin;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        <?php
        //This does not echo into the browser AND is not visible in "view source" either!
        if ( $redirectOrigin ) echo $redirectOrigin;
        ?>
    </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

**EDIT: I added another function that gets called only if you go directly to end.php instead of via a redirect. It does the same setting, retrieving and unsetting of the session variable, yet this one will work!**

**EDIT 2: More code to show the weirdness**

Compare these two functions. If you call function 1 (notice neither function checks the `isset()`), you'll get an error `Notice: Undefined index: redirectedFrom`. But if you call function 2, you won't get an error, it will exist. The only difference is the added unset call. And the error occurs on the line **prior** to the unset call!

```
    public function getRedirect1()
    {
        //Make sure we have a session
        session_start();

        //This should exist, but it throws an index error
        $redFrom = $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ];

        //Unset it
        unset( $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ] );

        return $redFrom;
    }

    public function getRedirect2()
    {
        //Make sure we have a session
        session_start();

        $redFrom = $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ];

        return $redFrom;
    }
```

Comment: Thinking about your issue some more. Is it really necessary to use sessions at all? 1.  Reads the session variable and stores it in a local variable 2. unsets the session variable 3. returns the local variable. Because you include the file red.php (in end.php) an object would be created and you could fetch the value from the object. (like return self::$file if class has a static variable $file="red.php")

Comment: I tried that but the static variable is recreated across calls. it's not static across a session, but only within that one request.

Comment: Look at my edited answer. I think that would be a better approach in your case. (serialization with sleep and wakeup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome is requesting the page twice (they do this to speed up responses).

This is a dumb solution but the only one I could get to work.

Notice I have to create two other session variables so that this doesn't keep returning true forever and so that the second check can also be unset, but I'll still be guaranteed to have a variable with the value after that unset.

```
<?php
class LandingRedirector
{
    private static $SESSION_VARIABLE = "redirectedFrom";
    private static $CHROME_SESSION_VARIABLE = "redirectedFromChrome";
    private static $CHROME_SESSION_VARIABLE_TO_READ = "redirectedFromChromeRead";

    function __construct() {}

    public function redirect()
    {
        //Make sure we have a session
        session_start();

        //Set the redirect variable
        $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ] = "red.php";
        $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ] = "red.php";

        session_write_close();

        //Redirect to correct page
        header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
        header( "Location: /end.php" );
        exit;
    }

    public function setonly()
    {
        //Make sure we have a session
        session_start();

        //Set the redirect variable
        $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ] = "red.php";

        session_write_close();
    }

    public function getRedirect()
    {
        try
        {
            //Make sure we have a session
            session_start();

            //It's set
            if ( isset( $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ] ) )
            {
                $redFrom = $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ];

                //This is to deal with Chrome's double request bug
                $_SESSION[ self::$CHROME_SESSION_VARIABLE ] = $redFrom;
                $_SESSION[ self::$CHROME_SESSION_VARIABLE_TO_READ ] = $redFrom;

                //Unset it
                unset( $_SESSION[ self::$SESSION_VARIABLE ] );

                return $redFrom;
            }

            //Not set, but is this a Chrome second request?
            else if ( isset( $_SESSION[ self::$CHROME_SESSION_VARIABLE ] ) )
            {
                $redFrom = $_SESSION[ self::$CHROME_SESSION_VARIABLE_TO_READ ];

                //Unset the one we check
                unset( $_SESSION[ self::$CHROME_SESSION_VARIABLE ] );

                return $redFrom;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {}

        return null;
    }
}

//Create
$redirector = new LandingRedirector();

//Redirect
if ( !isset( $stopHere ) || $stopHere != true ) $redirector->redirect();
?>
```

Comment: whats with Chrome requesting the page 2 more times? this is crazy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at the __sleep and __wakeup() ?  http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.magic-functions.php

If I understand you correctly you want to do something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

class LandingRedirector
{
    private $file = "red.php";

    function __sleep()
    {
        return array('file'); //Which variables you want to store when object do the serialization
    }

    function __construct() {}

    public function redirect()
    {   
        //Redirect to correct page
        //header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
        header( "Location: end.php" );
        exit;
    }

    public function setFile($nFile) {
        $this->file = $nFile;
    }

    public function getRedirect()
    {                   
        return $this->file;
    }
}

//Create new object if session does not exist. If it exist, then unserialize it
if (!isset($_SESSION['redirector'])) {
    $redirector = new LandingRedirector();
    $redirector->setFile('sausage.php');
    $_SESSION['redirector'] = serialize($redirector); //This calls __sleep() and serialize current object (or parts of it)
}
else {
    $redirector = unserialize($_SESSION['redirector']); //Unserialize will call __wakeup()
}
//Create

//Redirect
if ( !isset( $stopHere ) || $stopHere != true ) $redirector->redirect();
?>
```

The output of getRedirect() in end.php would be sausage.php

Comment: No, it doesn't print out anything. The script tags look like this: `<script>
  </script>` with nothing but empty space between them.

Comment: it claims it is down at the second call, but at the first call it echos an actual value.

Comment: You just have one call to getRedirect() ?

Comment: correct. Please see my edit. I added another function that shows the problem only exists when doing with a redirect.

Comment: hm. If you throw an exception with value of $e instead of returning null. What happens then? (in the getRedirect() - function))

Comment: nothing happens because no error is ever thrown. it doesn't even reach that.

Comment: Ok. If you try to add session_start() and session_close() outside of the class. Does that make any difference? (top and bottom of each of your php-files)

Comment: What happens if you just echo out echo $redirectOrigin; instead of: if ( $redirectOrigin ) echo $redirectOrigin; ?

Comment: To both questions: doesn't make a difference. :(

Comment: Please check my latest edits. I added two functions at the bottom of my post which show that calling unset **after** you retrieve it will cause an error to be thrown in the line **before** the unset call!

Comment: I agree - it's weird. What happens if you do a dump of the whole session-variable? like print_r($_SESSION,true) in getDirect1() and the same thing getRedirect2() - it might give a clue?

Comment: Your getDirect1() and getDirect2() example would make sense if getDirect1() is called twice.

Comment: I used `var_dump( $_SESSION )` The first function which calls unset dumps: `array(0) {}` and the second function dumps `array(1) {  ["redirectedFrom"]=>  string(7) "red.php" }`

Comment: As to it making sense if called twice, I know but I added a counter (as a static variable) and it shows a count of 1.

Comment: Its not an issue in FF? I actually think it makes sense if called twice because first call unsets the session.

Comment: hm. I suppose you've tried to restart /delete cache etc in google chrome. If you uncomment $stopHere = true; in your destination file, it's the same weird behaviour?

Comment: I *think* I may have figured it out! I set "count" as a session variable instead and it appears it is getting called twice and I think I know why! Google Chrome actually makes two requests for pages to attempt to speed things up (I forget the exact reasoning but I came across this once before) and I'll bet that's why there's two calls!

Comment: Ok that would make sense :-)

Comment: But how am I going to fix this? How do I know it's a google extra request and not the user actually requesting it again?

Comment: no that won't solve it. look at my answer below. it's a stupid solution but it works. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I would not have found the solution without it!

Comment: I'll give the new code a try but how does this avoid being called twice by chrome's two requests?

Comment: It doesn't matter how may times getDirect() is called because it's just returning the current value from $file in the current object stored in session. (No comparisions and not returning null etc)

Comment: that seems right, but is it really better performance to read/write to a file (in serializing and unserializing) than to store a few things in the session? I'd assume the session variables would be much faster and less of a load on the CPU/disk.

Comment: Sessions are saved in files either way. Underserialization takes a "lot" of memory, but I'm not sure that it would be slower then in your original code because your original code actually saves more sessions. In this code you just save a session once (one object). If it is important, you could always do a benchmark...

Comment: This is what is stored in the session: LandingRedirector Object ( [file:private] => sausage.php )   (after the serialization)